Search SonarQ in a specific folder of a project using WebAPI
I have a SonarQ project (key=MyProjectKey) with some folders under the root (FolderA, FolderB...); I want to get the number of issues for each these folders.
With
.../api/issues/search?branch=main&resolved=false&ps=1&componentKeys=MyProjectKey
I got the same total number of issues as reported on the SonarQ dashboard.
Then I would like to get the number of issues of this project but only for files in FolderA and all its sub-folders.
But when I try:

.../api/issues/search?branch=main&resolved=false&ps=1&componentKeys=MyProjectKey:FolderA I got 0 issues (I have no files in FolderA, only in sub-folders).
.../api/issues/search?branch=main&resolved=false&ps=1&componentKeys=MyProjectKey:FolderA/% I got all issues of all SonarQ projects.
.../api/issues/search?branch=main&resolved=false&ps=1&componentKeys=MyProjectKey,FolderA I got all issues of my project (including those in FolderB).
.../api/issues/search?branch=main&resolved=false&ps=1&componentKeys=MyProjectKey,FolderA/% I got all issues of all SonarQ projects.

Any idea which request to use to only have issues of my project only in FolderA? Thanks a lot.
